Best coding language to write code for the Solana chain?
I'm looking to figure out how to write up an Solana Escrow service, but I don't know the first thing about coding.
I've seen people use JavaScript, Anchor and Rust to do some Solana coding, I was just wondering which one is less complicated

It depends on what you are most familiar with. As you've mentioned, you can probably write Solana programs in various languages, some of which are more well-supported than others.
I'd recommend starting with Anchor, which is new, because of the generation of IDL and TS types for client-side development. You don't have to think about serialization and deserialization logic because the framework does it for you. Plus, almost everyone in the ecosystem is familiar with it, so you are bound to get help should you get stuck.
Check out the anchor escrow program example -> https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/escrow/anchor
If you fancy writing your program, check out the WIP poseidon -> https://poseidon.turbin3.com/
Solang also provides the ability to write Solana programs using solidity -> https://solana.com/news/solang-solana-solidity-evm
seahorse allows you to write Solana programs in python but it hasn't been updated in a year -> https://github.com/ameliatastic/seahorse-lang
